# error with Libreoffice TexMath

Tags: libre-office

I am experiencing a problem with TexMath extension for LibreOffice. This problem began when I installed the latest build of LibreOffice. I followed the instructions to download the texmath.oxt file, then went to tools -> extension manager and enabled the extension. The normal symbols for TexMath appeared in the toolbar. However, when I attempted to use it, it asked me to configure the appropriate paths for latex xelatex, dvipng and dvisvgm.

In order to confirm the correct paths, I opened a terminal and typed:

`which latex`

the return was as expected:

`/usr/bin/latex`

I repeated the same process for the other paths. however when I tried to save these paths, I received the following error message:

`the program latex was not found, please check its path`

I am very confused and frustrated. The other latex editors I have installed are working fine, so I don't believe that anything is fundamentally wrong with the installation.

However, to be sure, I reinstalled everything, including

`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

after completing this process, I am faced with exactly the same error in LibreOffice, despite latex working perfectly well in dedicated latex editors.

can anyone please give me some advice?

You may wonder why i don't just use a dedicated latex editor, which is a fair question. I use this feature in libreoffice extensively for note taking. I find that its just faster and easier for notes. I tend to only use dedicated latex editors for work that others will see (publication etc), and I find that I'm much slower.

If anyone could please give me some advice on how to fix this i would be eternally grateful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: same here for Fedora 35

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
If you have installed Libreoffice as a snapd package (containerized) it would hard to let it find the bin latex.
So, I tried to uninstall everything and install LibreOffice by rpm. And voilà!